# Whether to put method code in a VB.Net data storage class, or put it in a separate class?

Tags: vb.net, class, optimization

**TLDR summary**: (a) Should I include (lengthy) method code in classes which may spawn multiple objects at runtime, (b) does doing so cause memory usage bloat, (c) if so should I "outsource" the code to a class that is loaded only once and have the class methods call that, or alternatively (d) does the code get loaded only once with the object definition anyway and I'm worrying about nothing?

........

I don't know whether there's a good answer to this but if there is I haven't found it yet by searching in the usual places.

In my VB.Net (2010 if it matters) WinForms project I have about a dozen or so class objects in an object model. Some of these are pretty simple and do little more than act as data storage repositories. The ones further up the object model, however, have an increasing number of methods. There can be a significant number of higher level objects in use though the exact number will be runtime dependent so I can't be more precise than that.

As I was writing the method code for one of the top level ones I noticed that it was starting to get quite lengthy.

Memory optimisation is something of a lost art given how much memory the average PC has these days but I don't want to make my application a resource hog. So my questions for anyone who knows .Net way better than I do (of which there will be many) are:

- Is the code loaded into memory with each instance of the class that's created?
- Alternatively is it loaded only once with the definition of the class, and all derived objects just refer to that definition? (I'm not really sure how that could be possible given that, for example, event handlers can be assigned dynamically, but no harm asking.)
- If the answer to the first one is yes, would it be more efficient to write the code in a "utility" object which is loaded only once and called from the real class' methods?

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, it doesn't matter.  Your data is stored in memory but your code is loaded only once.

EDIT: I guess I need a longer answer.

If you have 10 instances of a class, the variables that are part of that instance all take up thier own memory space. So if you have 10 properties, variables, etc, that means you have 100(ish) items in your memory.  As for your code, it was loaded just once with your assembly. If you create 10 instances of your class, your code is not in memory 10 times.

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time for the longer one Steve. Out of curiosity have you come across any documentation on this? In my searches before posting the question I came across some specific topics such as the impact of garbage collection in memory consumption but not any general documentation on object memory handling. Given the replies here it's more an issue of curiosity than anything. Thanks for the response.

Comment: As for memory allocation of the variables, you can look at [Data Type Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7.aspx) to see how much memory each data type consume. As for the code, it's just something I know after programming for so long but I dont know where you might find a article on it. Tough to search on that one.

Comment: Tell me about it. The more specifiic an issue you come across, the easier it is to find references. The more generic, the harder it is because the material content is lost in the "noise" of things that use the same key search words but are irrelevant to what you're looking for. I'm going to flag this one as the answer. StingyJack's points were good and relevant but this one addressed the specific thing that I was asking. Thanks again both.

Answer (score 3):

Go with whichever is going to be the easier to maintain codebase (shorter methods, etc). That is the more important cost with anything that has increasing complexity.

Memory optimization is only a problem if its a problem. 12 classes is really nothing, when you have hundreds of instances of hundreds of classes, then it may become a problem.

Comment: All good points, StingyJack. I probably just feel a bit more comfortable when I know what the system is getting up to under the hood. Too many times in earlier applications I've come across things that should in theory work, but don't always (or don't work well) in practice, so I thought it worth the question. But you're dead on with regard to the complexity issue.